# Create log folder dynamically

Tags: logging, apache2

Is there a way to dynamically create a log folder structure? I browse google but I only find a way of changing log directory path. What I want to do is to keep the log file by date. Like apache2/2017/01/01/error.log. I'm using centos 7 LAMP stack and ubuntu 16.04 LTS LAMP stack.

```
apache2/
     -2017/
         -01/
             -01/error.log
             -02/error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a dynamic directory, you can write a script that detects current date (dd,mm,yyyy) and use mkdir command with '-p' switch to create it.

To ask apache httpd daemon to do it might be tricky. You might want to write a wrapper script script that gets executed on a cron job.

Or even trigger it via logrotate.... depending on date/time or states (logrotate)

Roughly here's how I will do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_YEAR=`date +%Y`
DATE_MONTH=`date +%m`
DATE_DAY=`date +%d`

mkdir -p /var/log/httpd/${DATE_YEAR}/${DATE_MONTH}/${DATE_DAY}
```

Example execution on cli:

```
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]# echo $DATE_YEAR
2017
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]# echo $DATE_MONTH
01
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]# echo $DATE_DAY
20
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]#
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]#
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]#
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]# mkdir -p ${DATE_YEAR}/${DATE_MONTH}/${DATE_DAY}


[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]# find ${DATE_YEAR}
2017
2017/01
2017/01/20
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]#

[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]# tree ${DATE_YEAR}
2017
└── 01
    └── 20

2 directories, 0 files
[root@backend-0-0 hello-world]#
```